# Delete selected cells from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to delete all the selected cell from when i swipe left.

My .m file

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{

    CGPoint location = [_gestureSwipeLeft locationInView:_tblThingsToDo];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [_tblThingsToDo indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    UITableViewCell *swipedCell  = [_tblThingsToDo cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];

    if (swipedCell.selected == NO) {
        swipedCell.selected = YES;
    }
    else{
    swipedCell.selected = NO;
    }
}


-(void)deleteCurrentobject:(id)sender{
    if(self.selectedCells){
        [_things removeObjectAtIndex:_indexPath.row];
        [self.tblThingsToDo deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:_indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

I want all the swipedCell.selected to be deleted when pressing on the button that calls the deleteCurrentObject method. How am i going to do that?

Comment: Add swipedCell.selected property under KVC and set your target method as a selector (i.e. deleteCurrentobject:) in KVC method context.

Comment: How do i do that? What's KVC?

Comment: KVC mean key Value coding. Go through this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE

Comment: Could you help me adding the swipedCell.selected property under KVC and set the target method as a selector?

Comment: can u show how you are calling the deleteCurrentobject: method

Comment: @Shan -(void)editButtonPressed:(id)sender{ UIBarButtonItem *deleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(deleteSelectedObjects:)]; self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = deleteButton; }

Comment: not the method, where are u calling this method..?

Answer (score 1):

Place below line stuff inside init method of swipedCell class otherwise swipedCell object creation time.

```
[self addObserver: swipedCell forKeyPath:@"selected" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

When you `handleSwipeLeft:` method called it will automatically call below method,

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
     if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"selected"] && [object isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
       if(object.selected){
       [_things removeObjectAtIndex:_indexPath.row];
         [self.tblThingsToDo beginUpdates];
         [self.tblThingsToDo deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:_indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
         [self.tblThingsToDo endUpdates];
      }
    }
}
```

On remove observer use below code stuff

```
[self removeObserver:swipedCell forKeyPath:@"selected"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{

    CGPoint location = [_gestureSwipeLeft locationInView:_tblThingsToDo];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [_tblThingsToDo indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    _indexPath = swipedIndexPath;
    UITableViewCell *swipedCell  = [_tblThingsToDo cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];

    if (swipedCell.selected == NO) {
        swipedCell.selected = YES;
    } else{
        swipedCell.selected = NO;
    }
}


-(void)deleteCurrentobject:(id)sender{
     if(self.selectedCells){
         [_things removeObjectAtIndex:_indexPath.row];
         [self.tblThingsToDo beginUpdates];
         [self.tblThingsToDo deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:_indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
         [self.tblThingsToDo endUpdates];
     }
}
```